# ASP.NET 4.5 C# Active Directory Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap, authorization, login-control

I used this for try login with LDAP in ASP.NET C# 4.5
If i try use this, i cant access nothing (For deny users=?)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<membership defaultProvider="ADConnection">
  <providers>
    <add name="ADConnection" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
          connectionProtection="Secure" connectionStringName="ADConnection" connectionUsername="cpdprt01" connectionPassword="prt2016" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
          enableSearchMethods="false"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Any solution to try block navigate for others pages without autentication?
(I can login with this data but i can't block not autentication connection)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean that unauthenticated users can still access the site?

Comment: totally confused, please make it simple

Comment: @GabrielLuci Sorry for my english.
I try to explain  ...
If i use this configuration nobody can access to my website but if i delete the line <deny users="?"> all users can access to my site.
The login control works correctly. My problem is with the authorization

Comment: Are you able to log in using the login control?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, i can access with this control. I try to use this:
Username: cpdprt01
Password: prt2016

If i try to use an other user that not exist, the control say me "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again." (My Failure Text)

Comment: All of this sounds normal and correct. :) What is the problem then?

Comment: @GabrielLuci The login control is perfect but i can access other pages without authetication only write URL in nav bar (For Example: http://localhost/Default.aspx or http://localhost/Terceros.aspx and don't redirect to Login.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what the problem is, but I'll explain how it is supposed to work, and maybe that will help.

`?` means anonymous users.

`*` means everyone.

So `<deny users="?"/>` means it will disallow access to anonymous (unauthenticated) users.

However, that does not apply to the page that you specify as the `loginUrl` in the `<forms>` tag. Any unauthenticated user can access that page, so they can login.

If it is not redirecting to your Login page, then try adding `applicationName` to your provider:

```
<add name="ADConnection" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionProtection="Secure" connectionStringName="ADConnection" connectionUsername="cpdprt01" connectionPassword="prt2016" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
      enableSearchMethods="false" applicationName="Something" />
```

Comment: If i try use this, the result is this: http://puu.sh/oEKUG/d180f9e4c1.png
I can't access to login.aspx

Comment: So it is not redirecting to Login.aspx when it should? Try adding `applicationName` attribute to your provider (I updated my answer).

Comment: If i use IISExpress for VisualStudio can see my login control http://puu.sh/oEMAk/c5815984b8.png but i can enter  in others pages without authentication. 
If i use My IIS with this configuration:http://puu.sh/oEMyV/b9ec5db66f.png i cant enter nothing
I change applicationName="Something" for applicationName="Expedientes"

Comment: Do you still have `<deny users="?"/>` in your web.config? You do need it.

Comment: When you say you can access nothing in IIS, do you mean you cannot access the Login page either?

Comment: If i try access, the application redirect me to Login.aspx but i haven't access to this page